# Обновление Chart в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

На форме имеется 5 элементов chart, их нужно обновлять каждый определённый промежуток времени, при этом ,чтобы в этот момент с окном программы можно было взаимодействовать.

```
` private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(5); }));
            Invoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(30); }));
            Invoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(60); }));
            Invoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(360); }));
            Invoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(720); }));
            Invoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(1440); }));
            Invoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(2880); }));
        }`
```

Сейчас у меня вот такой код, но в момент срабатывания таймера вся форма намертво зависает на некоторое время.
Каким образом можно обновлять chart в отдельном потоке, для того ,Чтобы главное окно программы не висло?

---

Попробовал вот так

```
 private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Invoke(new Action<int>(getinfo), 5);
            chart2.Invoke(new Action<int>(getinfo), 30);
            chart3.Invoke(new Action<int>(getinfo), 60);
            chart4.Invoke(new Action<int>(getinfo), 360);
            chart5.Invoke(new Action<int>(getinfo), 720);
            chart6.Invoke(new Action<int>(getinfo), 1440);
            chart7.Invoke(new Action<int>(getinfo), 2880);

        }
```

Форма точно также зависает

---

Через делегаты точно также зависает

---

Загрузил проект на яндекс диск https://yadi.sk/d/E0tkXFlsgX-3qw

Comment: Используй асинхронные методы. 
async Task

Comment: В дотнете есть несколько разных таймеров. Какой именно используется? Укажите в вопросе. Так-то понятно, что это `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Его события вызываются в gui-потоке. Естественно, что форма виснет, пока не завершится обработчик события `Tick`. Самым простым способом, вероятно, будет использование `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: попробовал   BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { getinfo(5); })); точно так же вся форма зависает

Comment: await Task.Run(() => { getinfo(5); }); если сделать так, то просто ошибку выбивает

Comment: А, так у вас сам метод `getinfo` выполняется долго. Значит, действительно, нужно выполнять код в другом потоке/таске.

Comment: Есть же механизм биндинга данных к контролам и специальные коллекции вроде BindingList для автоматического отображения измененных данных. Делаете привязку DataSource на такую коллекцию и меняйте ее в отдельном потоке как нравится - остальное Chart сам сделает. Ну и стоит добавить к вопросу частоту вызова обновлений и длительность выполнения вызываемых методов, а то может вы хотите обновлять данные настолько часто, что нужно применять обновление с буферизацией

Comment: сделал вот так, не помогло  private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy == true)
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
           

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            getinfo(5);
          getinfo(30);
            getinfo(60);
            getinfo(360);
            getinfo(720);
            getinfo(1440);
            getinfo(2880);
        }

Comment: сделал вот так . всё лагает  private async void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)delegate { getinfo(5); });
            this.Invoke((Action)delegate { getinfo(30); });
            this.Invoke((Action)delegate { getinfo(60); });


            })
            { IsBackground = true }.Start();


        }

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос. Самое главное: что происходит внутри метода `getinfo`?

Comment: я скинул проект, посмотрите там. Там отправляется запрос на сайт, получается информация в джсон формате, далее она суммируется и закидывается на 3 лэйбла и чарт